# Database returns only first row

Tags: php, mysqli

It's pretty strange, but when I execute the query "SELECT * FORM table" it only returns the first row, but when I execute "SELECT * FORM table WHERE id = 2", I do get the second row. Can someone pls help me with this?

Here's my code:
DB class,

```
class DB
{
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_conn,
        $_query,
        $_error = false,
        $_result,
        $_count = 0;

    /**
     *
     */
    private function __construct()
    {
        $servername = Config::get("mysql/host");
        $username   = Config::get("mysql/username");
        $password   = Config::get("mysql/password");
        $database   = Config::get("mysql/db");

        $this->_conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    }


    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
            self::$_instance = new DB;
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }


    public function query($sql)
    {
        $this->_error = false;

        if ($this->_query = $this->_conn->query($sql)) {
            $this->_result = $this->_query->fetch_object();
            $this->_count = $this->_query->num_rows;
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    private function action($action, $table, $where = array())
    {
        if(count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

            $field      = $where[0];
            $operator   = $where[1];
            $value      = $where[2];

            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} '{$value}'";

                if (!$this->query($sql)->error()) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        } elseif (count($where) === 0) {
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table}";

            if (!$this->query($sql)->error()) {
                return $this;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function get($table, $where = array())
    {
        return $this->action("SELECT *", $table, $where);
    }
```

Index.php,

```
    $db = DB::getInstance();
    $results1 = $db->get('pages')->results();
    $results2 = $db->get('pages', ["id", "=", 2])->results();

    var_dump($results1); // Returns first row
    var_dump($results2); // Returns second row
```

It's a strange thing in my opinion. $result1 should return all rows, right? I expect it has something to do with the ->fetch_object in the query method from the DB class. I have searched there for the problem but I couldn't find it and thus php.net the fetch_object method can return more then one row. Does someone have any idea and can he help me?

**UPDATE:** when I ask for a count, it does return the correct number of rows in the database, but stil it won't be in the $_result property

Comment: Please stop making singleton database wrappers and learn to use dependency injection. What you are doing is actually making the code both more insecure and harder to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You only call [`fetch_object`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) once.

> The mysqli_fetch_object() will return **the current row** result set as an object where the attributes of the object represent the names of the fields found within the result set.

As per the documentation…

> ```
> while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
>     printf ("%s (%s)\n", $obj->Name, $obj->CountryCode);
> }
> ```

… you need to call it in a loop until there are no more objects to fetch.

Comment: But what if I dont know the column names? I can do requests to more then one table with this class.

Comment: @kabamgamer — You don't need to know the column names to call `fetch_object`.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid mind, but I dont get it. Can you show me what code I should use. Because if I do this:
while ($this->_result = $this->_query->fetch_object()) {
                printf ("%s (%s)\n", $this->_result->id, $this->_result->user);
            }

It works, but only with one table

Comment: Replace `printf ("%s (%s)\n", $obj->Name, $obj->CountryCode);` with code that does the thing you want to do with the data. (i.e. assign it to `result` … which you probably want to make an array to push all the rows into).

Comment: Do I get you wrong? I have changed the code. Now I get errors like 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Name in /var/www/html/classes/DB.php on line 50

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$CountryCode in /var/www/html/classes/DB.php on line 50
()

Comment: @kabamgamer — Yes. You appear to have **kept** the code I said to **replace**.

Comment: Can you please add a new answer or edit this one to show me how my code should be?